# A paper's citations per year?

Tags: publications, citations, google-scholar

Google Scholar shows the total number of citations per year for anyone with an account there:

[image]

Is it possible to see a similar figure just for one publication?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, click on the article title and scroll down in the dialog. You can hover over the bars to get raw count.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I never noticed this little figure. Unfortunately, it doesn't show the Y-axis, and the plot is kind of squashed, so it can be hard to see trends.